# Gems for rake DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, rake, dbmigrate

Good day
What I have add to gem file ?
And how install ?

TODONE: 
added: gem 'rake', '0.8.7' 
run: > bundle install 
or run: > bundle install rake
All it's not work 
Thank You

[image]

**Gemfile**

    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
    gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
    gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
    end
    group :development do
      gem 'web-console'
      gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
      gem 'spring'
      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
    end
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
    gem 'activerecord'
    gem 'actionpack'
    gem 'actionmailer'
    gem 'actionwebservice'
    gem 'settingslogic'
    gem 'authlogic'
    gem 'calendar_date_select'
    gem 'cgi_multipart_eof_fix'
    gem 'daemon_controller'
    gem 'daemons'
    gem 'file-tail'
    gem 'gem_plugin'
    gem 'i18n'
    gem 'mini_portile'
    gem 'multi_json'
    gem 'permutation'
    gem 'polyglot'
    gem 'rack'
    gem 'rake', '0.8.7' #'10.0.4' **Here added 'rake'** 
    gem 'ruby-ole'
    gem 'rufus-scheduler'
    gem 'tins'
    gem 'treetop'
    gem 'will_paginate'
    gem 'ya2yaml'
    gem 'rdoc'
    gem 'mime-types'
    gem 'mysql2'
    gem 'active_scaffold', git: 'https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold.git' 
    gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
    gem 'activerecord-session_store'
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?

Comment: It could be because that is a **very** old version of rake. The latest version is 13.0.6. Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: /* Gemfile here */

Comment: Try with `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and use a recent version of `rake` (0.8.7 seems quite old).

Comment: I set   gem 'rake', '11.2.2' 
I go to my project directory in 'cmd' and run ) : bundle exec rake db:migrate
Anything happen or run (